# How can I design a database schema to store data which is having n-ary Tree format

Tags: database, database-design, relational-database, database-schema

How can I store data in database which is having the relationship like a n-ary tree. For example consider the scenario in the following diagram:
(All the nodes are having the same data objects.)

```
                             c1
                    /  |     |      \
                  c11  c12  c13      c14
                 / |     |    |     /    |    |   \
              c111 c112 c121 c131  c141 c142 c143 c144
              / | \  |   /|\\ / \   |    / \
```

Please suggest the best option to store the data having the above format in a database. Please suggest considering the database queries so that the information can be easily loaded in the memory.

Comment: I may be wrong but, an Object Relational Mapper is probably your best bet. Given you probably want to pull out all related entity in one query. There may be a better solution out there though :)

Answer (score 1):

The normalized way is to store a foreign key `parent_id` with each element, containing the id value of the parent element. This is optimal in the sense that there is no redundancy, so updates to the tree structure only affect the database records of the updated items. Also, queries are straightforward, e.g. finding all siblings of an element containing its `:id` and its `:parent_id` means

```
select * from item
where id <> :id
and parent_id = :parent_id;
```

If you have extremely high performance requirements, you might sacrifice normalization. But this can only be decided by knowing the typical and maximum depth and breadth of the tree, and the type and frequency of update and read operations. But the general rule is not to bring that kind of sacrifice unless measurements on realistic data prove that there is a need for them.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example in PostgreSQL. This pattern is called an Adjacency List.

```
create table kary_tree (
  node_id int primary key,
  label text not null,
  parent_node_id int null references kary_tree(node_id)
);
```

You would need some triggers to enforce the maximum number of children per parent. Here's an example for a ternary tree:

```
create function ternary_tree_trigger() returns trigger language plpgsql as $$
declare
  MAX_KIDS constant int = 3;
begin

  if (select count(*) from kary_tree where parent_node_id = NEW.parent_node_id) >= MAX_KIDS then
        raise exception 'too many kids';
  end if;

  return NEW;
end $$;

create trigger inserting before insert on kary_tree for each row execute procedure ternary_tree_trigger();
```

You'd want a similar trigger for updates.

You would use [Recursive Common Table Expressions](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/queries-with.html) to query such a tree. Here's an example: http://blog.databasepatterns.com/2014/02/trees-paths-recursive-cte-postgresql.html